# MySQL Restore - DB Tables with Prefix and SQL Script with No Prefix

Tags: sql, mysql

In command line, I'm trying to restore some (not all) tables of data from an MySQL SQL script file. However, my single database tables have a prefix and the sql file tables does not.

Is there a way within the command line to specify a prefix on restore?

```
mysql -uroot -p databasename < script_with_no_prefix.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick out the tables you need using a `sed` command. For example, if your table prefix is "prefix_", you could use this:

```
$ sed -n -e '/^-- Table structure for table `prefix_/,/^UNLOCK TABLES/p' \
  script_with_no_prefix.sql | mysql -uroot -p databasename
```